# Switch Content of two Textareas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, innerhtml

I have two textareas and I like to switch the content of these, so content of the first textarea shall be the content of the second textarea and vice versa. Following code just copy the content of the first textarea into the second, but the second step is not performed, so both textareas comprise the same content afterwards. No error occurs.

```
function switch_text_content(){
     
    var src_text_memory = src_form.src_message.value;
    var trgt_text_memory = trgt_form.trgt_message.value;
    console.log(src_text_memory);
    src_form.src_message.innerHTML = trgt_text_memory;
    trgt_form.trgt_message.innerHTML = src_text_memory;
    //switch_text_content2(trgt_text_memory);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in wrong way because you are using `.innerHTML` to set value instead you can to use `.value` property to set value of textarea. Like Below Example:

```js
const switchBtn = document.querySelector('#switch-btn');
const firstTextarea = document.querySelector('#first-textarea');
const secondTextarea = document.querySelector('#second-textarea');

switchBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const firstContent = firstTextarea.value;
  const secondContent = secondTextarea.value;
  
  firstTextarea.value = secondContent;
  secondTextarea.value = firstContent;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="first-textarea">First Content</textarea>

<textarea id="second-textarea">Second Content</textarea>

<br/>

<button type="button" id="switch-btn">Switch</button>
```